# How to use regex flags in Mariadb's regexp_replace?

Tags: mysql, regex, mariadb

I have a table with records. A record has a field `content` that contains some html like `<p><a href=\"/pictures/image.jpg\" class=\"highslide\" onclick=\"return hs.expand(this)\"><img src=\"/pictures/image.jpg\" vspace=\"6\" hspace=\"6\" align=\"left\" alt=\"Alt text\" title=\"Title Text\" width=\"260\"></a> Some text content...`

I need to remove `<a></a>` tags that are now placed around `<img>`. There can be multiple `<a><img></a>` occurrences in the string. I kinda made a corresponding regexp and learnt about `REGEXP_REPLACE` function. Ideally I expect something like

```
UPDATE table_name SET content = REGEXP_REPLACE(content, '/<a\shref=\\?"\/pictures\/.+">(<img.+">)<\/a>/gmU', '\\1') WHERE id=1
```

to work out, but it doesn't. I don't understand where to put flags `gmU`. Also in the articles/docs I found on the internet I don't see flags like `g` (global) and `U` (ungreedy). Is it global and ungreedy by default? How to make it all work? 
10.3.15-MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MariaDB you pass flags to `REGEXP_REPLACE` by in-lining them in the regex using `(?x)` notation, where `x` is the flag. `REGEXP_REPLACE` by default replaces *all* occurrences of pattern in the string, so you don't need the `g` flag; nor in your case do you need the multi-line flag `m` as you are not attempting to use beginning/end of line anchors. You can use `U` though in place of the `?` modifier to make `+` non-greedy.

There's a couple of issues with your regex:

1. MariaDB does not require regexes to be contained with `/`
2. `\s` represents a literal `s` and needs to be `\\s`
3. To match a literal `\` you need to use `\\\\`, not `\\`

This regex should give you the results you want:

```
(?U)<a\\s.*href=\\\\?"/pictures.+(<img.+>)</a>
```

In a query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(content, '(?U)<a\\s.*href=\\\\?"/pictures.+(<img.+>)</a>', '\\1')
FROM test
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=99f69fdf0b6249e6bf543ebe649402b3)

Comment: I expect the doubling of backslash to depend on the number of client layers you are going through.

Comment: @RickJames yes - this answer is for a query entered directly into MariaDB where the parser eats the first backslashes and so you need a second set to end up with `\ ` . `\\?` would just be treated as a literal `?` by the regex engine.